Error in rtweet: “Error in check_scopes(): ! This endpoint requires missing scopes”
I am using rtweet and after following the authentication process by running the following code:
tweets_migration <- tweet_search_all(“migration”, n = 10, parse = TRUE)

I get the following error:

Error in check_scopes():
! This endpoint requires missing scopes.
• Authenticate with scopes:‘tweet.moderate’

does anyone know how to fix this?
I was trying to learn how to scrape twitter (X) to obtain information for a research that I am conducting on migration issues.

You basically can't do anything with the twitter ("X"... whatever LOL what a joke) API anymore unless you have paid Elon and are an authenticated API user. This means the vast majority of functionality in rtweet is broken unless you have paid for access.

I am the last maintainer. The package is no longer maintained. But you need to add a scope in the client to be able to use that endpoint.
